# User Entity is not working in Alpha Release

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have developed an Action for google assistant using Dialogflow v1, everything is working perfectly in a developer version,  but once I have submitted it for the Alpha release, the user entity not working for the alpha version or with the testers account. 
I have checked my logs and it shows me that user entity is created successfully but it didn't detect it in the slot filing.
I have also tested it with the Get request from Postman with the same sessionId and successfully get the entities but I understand why it is not detecting in slot filing in Alpha version.

I have attached the video also about the issue, Please help me to resolve this.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y2zSKqcZ3OTey_RGnRxHMZfFVhP5oSlh/view

Comment: Are you using Dialogflow for this? Can you see if the issue is related to Dialogflow? Is there a reason you're using v1 at the moment instead of v2?

Comment: @Nike Felker I start working on this app three months ago, at that time i am not familiar with V2, and found some of the glitch in V2, that why i decided to develop it on V1, but i understand what the problem actually is? It works perfectly with developer version and not working perfectly in Alpha version

Comment: Maybe you need to click **UPDATE** on the Actions integration in the Dialogflow Integrations section.

Comment: @NickFelker I have updated it. Should I need to deploy again for alpha version?

Comment: You shouldn't have to deploy again, but I would just in case

Comment: @NickFelker I have updated it, still not working in Alpha version.

Answer (score 3):

I got stuck with this same issue a few weeks ago, after a looong conversation with AOG support I got this answer : 
"I had to do some digging. Currently, the session entities arent available for alpha/beta/prod AoG versions."

Comment: if this is the reason then why they do not mention it in the documentation

Comment: Are you using session entities, defined at runtime, or developer entities, defined ahead of time?

Comment: @NickFelker i am using this: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/userentities

Comment: Entities are predefine in the dialogflow console, I just added values in it based on user's sessionId (they call it User Entity), and it works perfect with developer version, only the issue is with alpha realease.

Comment: User Entity is the name in V1 api, User Session is in V2 and V2beta1 API. I tryed the 3 version of the API, it always works in draft and never in alpha. the solution proposed by AOG/Dialogflow support was to use @sys.any